# How to ERET to the same exception level in ARMv8?

Tags: assembly, arm

It is known how to return from exception level to the previous exception level (set elr_el3 -> set spsr_el3 -> execute eret), but how to ERET from EL3 to the same EL3? In official documentation from ARM I've found the sentence which says that it is possible:
"Returning from an exception can stay at the same Exception level or enter a lower Exception level. It cannot move to a higher Exception level.".

Comment: maybe it means you cant get lower than el0 and stay in el0.

Comment: Interesting point of view :) But in documentation I found info that ERET at EL0 is of undefined behavior.

Comment: yeah, cant find the answer either...says that PSTATE comes from SPSR but spsr doesnt contain el bits.

Answer (score 8):

The ERET instruction can be used to return to the same or any lower exception level that the CPU supports. If the saved mode fields stored in `SPSR_EL3.M[4:0]` are set to `0b01101` or `0b01100`, where bits `M[3:2]` encode an exception level of 3, then an ERET instruction executed at EL3 will return to EL3.

See section "D1.6.4 Saved Program Status Registers (SPSRs)" in the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual -- ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile)  for more details on how the SPSR_ELx registers are laid out.